# How to POST and GET a model with Foreign Key

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, foreign-keys

I am working on a NextJS + Django REST Framework project where I have three models; Document, MySource, and QuestionBlock.

1. Document is created along with several “question_blocks” linked to the created document. They are created together, and I have already implemented this with nested serializers.
2. After the Document is created, I want to be able to POST a MySource model linked to the document. Then, when I make a GET request of a document, all mysource objects should be displayed as well.

**POST request: notice how I just put the document’s id that I want to link with.**

```
{
  "url": "urlasdf",
  "title": "tuitle",
  "publisher": "afdfas ",
  "desc": "qwefqwef",
  "summary": "asdfasdf",
  "document": "J9DY2pE"
}
```

**GET request: I want the document GET request to show something like below.**

```
"id": "LwpQr6Y",
    "question_blocks": [
        {
            "id": 16,
            "document": "LwpQr6Y",
            "title": "question 4",
            "content": "qweqgadssdffasdf asdf"
        },
        ]
    "mysource": [
                {
            "id": 16,
            "url": "google.com",
            etc. . .
        },
        ],
    "title": "renamed title",
    "template": "commonapp",
    "updated": "2022-05-19T02:16:00+0000",
    "created": "2022-04-21T06:59:05+0000"
```

The weird part is that I do not see any errors with the code below, and the functionality itself is working properly. But when I attempt to GET the document which has at least one mysource object, it takes at a couple minutes to load, which is making me think there’s something wrong with my code that is perhaps making DRF repeat itself.

models.py

```
class Document(models.Model):
    id = HashidAutoField(primary_key=True)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=100, default="Untitled")
    template = models.CharField(max_length=100, default="")
    updated = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
    created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title

class QuestionBlock(models.Model):
    id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    document = models.ForeignKey(
        Document,
        related_name="question_blocks",
        on_delete=models.CASCADE,
        null=True,
        blank=True,
    )
    title = models.CharField(max_length=500, default="")
    content = models.CharField(max_length=100000, default="", blank=True)

class MySource(models.Model):
    id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    document = models.ForeignKey(
        Document,
        related_name="mysource",
        on_delete=models.CASCADE,
        null=True,
        blank=True,
    )
    url = models.CharField(max_length=500, default="")
    title = models.CharField(max_length=500, default="", blank=True)
    publisher = models.CharField(max_length=500, default="", blank=True)
    desc = models.CharField(max_length=500, default="", blank=True)
    summary = models.CharField(max_length=500, default="", blank=True)
```

serializers.py

```
class MySourceSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = MySource
        fields = ("id", "url", "title", "publisher", "desc", "summary")

    def to_representation(self, instance):
        self.fields["document"] = DocumentSerializer(read_only=True)
        return super(MySourceSerializer, self).to_representation(instance)


class DocumentSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    id = HashidSerializerCharField(source_field="documents.Document.id", read_only=True)
    question_blocks = QuestionBlockSerializer(many=True)
    mysource = MySourceSerializer(many=True)

    class Meta:
        model = Document
        fields = "__all__"

    def create(self, validated_data):
        question_blocks = validated_data.pop("question_blocks")
        document = Document.objects.create(**validated_data)
        for qBlock in question_blocks:
            QuestionBlock.objects.create(document=document, **qBlock)
        document.save()
        return document
```

**EDIT**: adding the QuestionBlockSerializer for more context

```
class QuestionBlockSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    document = serializers.PrimaryKeyRelatedField(
        pk_field=HashidSerializerCharField(source_field="documents.Document.id"),
        read_only=True,
    )

    class Meta:
        model = QuestionBlock
        fields = "__all__"
        optional_fields = ["content"]
```

Answer (score 2):

I think that an appropriate way to do this maybe be this one:

```
###imports
from django.forms.models import model_to_dict


class DocumentListingField(serializers.RelatedField):
    def to_representation(self, instance):
        return model_to_dict(instance.document)
```

and then in MySourceSerializer remove the to_representation function and update to something like this:

```
class MySourceSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    document = DocumentListingField(many=False, read_only=True)

    class Meta:
        model = MySource
        fields = (
            "id", "url", "title", "publisher", "desc", "summary", "document")
```

*Edit: I added the read_only set to True, 'caus the those models are using Hashfields thar are not easily selializable.

**edit:The reason that cause the slow response it's becaus you have a circle call of serializators so the system never know when to stop.
right here:

```
class MySourceSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    def to_representation(self, instance):
        ...
        self.fields["document"] = DocumentSerializer(read_only=True) 
        #Mysource its calling Documentserializer
            ...
    #And here:
class DocumentSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    ...
    mysource = MySourceSerializer(many=True) #this one its calling the MysorceSerialize, so there are a endless loop recursion
```

source : [Django Rest Framework-Custom relational fields](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/relations/)

Comment: the first code block is supposed to go under serializers.py, right? I'm getting the following error: "AssertionError: Relational field must provide a `queryset` argument, override `get_queryset`, or set read_only=`True`."

Comment: Yes, in the serializers.py, that error means that you need to set the property read_only=True.
like this:
class MySourceSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    document = DocumentListingField(many=False, read_only=True)

Comment: Thank you! all the GET part is working properly, but I'm not sure how POSTing a new MySource object works anymore. I can create a new MySource object but it is not linking to the document object. However previously created MySources are correctly reflected in GET requests.

Comment: also, the "document = DocumentListingField(many=False, read_only=True)" was giving me the following error > "'Document' object has no attribute 'document'"; however, fixing the document to Document with a capital D solved the problem. Just mentioning it here in case it helps with problem-solving!